# Include Likes and Share in meta on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, meta-tags

Site URL: http://intulife.de/blog/

Hi,

**I want to change the meta of a post in Wordpress from ("0 Kommentare") as it is right now (see website link) to [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSEFF.png) ("0 Kommentare . 10 Likes . Teilen").**

- "Kommentare" mean "Comments" in German
- "Teilen" means "Share" in German

This should include a connection to facebook for every post.

I did a lot of research but couldn't find any plugin that seemed to include the desired functionality. I might need to hard code something but my php knowledge is very limited.

**I hope you guys can give me some hints in which direction I should go to reach the desired goal.**

Comment: you can check this plugin link https://wordpress.org/plugins/only-tweet-like-share-and-google-1/

Comment: for comment : https://wordpress.org/plugins/disqus-comment-system/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Facebook graph API SDK to find the no. of likes on each post and include that javascript on each post you write.

here is the sample code of how you can do it but before that, you have to register for Facebook API on facebook developer console.

```
FB.api(
    "/{object-id}/likes",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

If you need more help comment below i will be more than happy to help